# Simplify the expression in the question below.

Tags: trigonometry

I have a problem with the question posted below:

[image: Image of the question]

I have been trying for a long time but I'm unable to simply this expression. The $(a+b)(a-b) $ like term gives us some hint but I'm not able to continue this pattern.

Would someone please help me to solve this question? 
Thanks for help.

Comment: Have you tried pluggin in the given $n$ along with the given $\theta$'s?

Comment: You don’t need to simplify, if all you need is to find a correct answer.  Hint: $\cos(\pi/3)=1/2$

Comment: you can't simplify, but it ist easy to just use your calculator to do the few products.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

Use $\cos2t=2\cos^2t-1$

$$(2\cos t+1)(2\cos t-1)=\cdots=2(1+\cos2t)-1$$

$$f_n(t)=2\cos2^nt+1$$

Another way:

$2\cos2x+1=2(1-2\sin^2x)+1=\dfrac{\sin3x}{\sin x}$ for $\sin x\ne0$

Similarly $2\cos2x-1=\dfrac{\cos3x}{\cos x}$ for $\cos x\ne0$